# How To Access Start And End Dates Of FullCalendar

Tags: ajax, vbscript, fullcalendar

I want to access ajax code to select the events to display on the calendar based on the start and end dates displayed.  How do I access those dates so I can pass them through the URL to my SQL query? I don't want to return all the events without regard to date because that could be a very large recordset for some users.

So far, I have

```
events: {
     'ajax.asp?serverside=PopulateCalendar'
}
```

I'm picturing something like

```
events: {
     'ajax.asp?serverside=PopulateCalendar?Start_Date=##/##/20##&End_Date=##/##/20##'
}
```

but I have no idea of how to access the start and end dates.  Any ideas?

Comment: FullCalendar automatically send a GET request with the date range it needs events for. See [events](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/) documentation. `FullCalendar will visit the URL whenever it needs new event data. This happens when the user clicks prev/next or changes views. FullCalendar will determine the date-range it needs events for and will pass that information along in GET parameters.`

Comment: Thanks @Ryan89.  So how do I access that from the ajax page?  I've looked at the events documentation, but I don't see any examples that I can fully interpret.  Exactly what parameters would my query expect?

Comment: I only know for php, the default would be GET['start'] and GET['end']. In vbscript it would be whatever the equivalent is to php GET. You can also set the parameter names to a custom value if you want. I believe the same documentation page says how.

Comment: They are in the [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), named **start** and **end** by default, and they are in [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format in v2 and v3 (v1 used [unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)). You tagged 'vbscript' I assume ASP.NET? See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1 for accessing the variables

Comment: That works!  In VBScript, it's Response.QueryString("start) and Response.QueryString("end).  Now I just have to figure out how to get the results into the calendar.  My query fields are: Event_Type (because I'm returning two types of events), Event_ID, Title, Start_Date, and End_Date.  I tried using the custom parameters when defining the calendar, but I don't think I'm doing it correctly.
eventSources:
[
 {
 url: 'ajax.asp?serverside=PopulateCalendar',
 type: 'Post',
 data:{
  start:'Start_Date',
  end: 'End_Date',
  title: 'Title',
  id:  '"' + 'Event_ID' + '"'
  }
 }
]